# Matrix pointer deallocation issue

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, matrix

I get this error while running the following program (it execute the code perfectly but looks like there are some issues about pointers/memory). thanks in advance for your help...

This is the message i get:

REVIEW(8310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100103b80: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(lldb)

My code:

In file Matrix.h

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{

   private:
T** M;
// unsigned numCol, numRow;
unsigned minRowIndex, maxRowIndex;
unsigned minColIndex, maxColIndex;




public:

Matrix();  // default constructor



Matrix(const unsigned& _numRow,
       const unsigned& _numCol,
       const T& value,
       const unsigned& _minRowIndex = 0,
       const unsigned& _minColIndex = 0);

~Matrix();


void Print();

T& operator() (const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col);
```

};

```
 template<typename T>
 Matrix<T> :: Matrix()

 {

     maxRowIndex = 9;
     maxColIndex = 9;

      unsigned i,j;

      M = new T*[maxRowIndex + 1];

     for (i =  minRowIndex; i < maxRowIndex; i++)
          M[i] = new T[maxColIndex + 1];

     for (i = minRowIndex; i < maxRowIndex; i++)
         for (j = minColIndex; j < maxColIndex; j++)
              M[i][j] = 0;

  }

   template<typename T>
    Matrix<T> :: Matrix( const unsigned& _numRow,
                 const unsigned& _numCol,
                 const T& value,
                 const unsigned& _minRowIndex,
                 const unsigned& _minColIndex)

   {

       minRowIndex = _minRowIndex;
       minColIndex = _minColIndex;
        maxRowIndex = _minRowIndex + _numRow - 1;
            maxColIndex = _minColIndex + _numRow - 1;

     unsigned i,j;

        M = new T*[maxRowIndex + 1];

      for (i =  minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
          M[i] = new T[maxColIndex + 1];

      for (i = minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
           for (j = minColIndex; j <= maxColIndex; j++)
               M[i][j] = value;
 }


 template<typename T>
 Matrix<T> :: ~Matrix()
 {
       for (unsigned i = 0; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
           delete[] M[i];

        delete[] M;
 }


 template<typename T>
 void Matrix<T> :: Print()
 {
        unsigned i,j;

       for (i = minRowIndex ; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
           for (j = minColIndex; j <= maxColIndex; j++)
       {
         cout << M[i][j] << "   ";

         if (j == maxColIndex)
            cout << endl;
       }

   cout << endl;cout << endl;

 }

   template<typename T>
   T& Matrix<T> :: operator() (const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col)
    {
          return  M[row][col];
    }
```

In file main.cpp

```
      #include "Matrix.h"


      using namespace std;

  int s(Matrix<int> L)
   {

      return L(2,2);
   }



 int main()
 {

     Matrix<int> L (5,5,100);
     cout << "L(2,2) = " << s(L) << endl << endl;

     return 0;    
 }
```

Comment: You need to do some debugging on your own. Find where exactly the issue occurs, and show only the code necessary to reproduce your problem. This is simply a code dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes that allocate fields using `new` and `delete` should have copy constructors and overload `operator=`. Failing to do so will use the default forms where fields are simply copied.

In your case, `T** M` is copied during the call to `s(L)` and upon return, the copy is destructed, causing deletes for all the arrays. At the end of main, another destruction takes place, but now the pointers refer to already freed blocks.

For function `s`, you might also pass a reference to avoid copying (but this doesn't solve the general problem).

Comment: could you explain  in more detail why I need a copy constructors and overload operator= ?  (I understood what happens but not why we need exactly this solution). thanks